# How to get all rows on basis of a condition from entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building a website using MVC ASP.Net. In the website when user clicks a category, then i want to find all the items having that category as foreign key from entity framework database.
I came across method of Find() but it doesn't fulfill my requirement.
What I want is something like

```
Database1Entities.Categories.Select(x => x.Cat_Id == Id);
```

But I dont know the exact way to do this.
Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @haim770, sorry, saw the comment after posting my answer :)

Comment: @AmmarCSE, That's OK. I'm not sure appending `ToList()` is a good idea though. Pre-materializing the query is probably not what the OP wants and it will prevent him from further performing additional Linq-to-Entities methods (like `OrderBy`, `Select` etc).

Comment: @haim770, I only did it because I saw he had Select(). So instead of doing Select(new Object{}) I just did .ToList....(disclaimer) I am not an expert in LINQ

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly fine, I will mark the answer as accepted as soon as stackoverflow allows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using [Where()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509017.aspx)

```
Database1Entities.Categories.Where(x => x.Cat_Id == Id);
```